# type error indexOf() is not a function in for loop

Tags: javascript

I saw there were other questions with a similar name, I looked through them and they didn't really have the same specific problem as mine.

For some reason the indexOf() is called not a function in my for loop. Tried testing outside the loop and it is just fine so unsure of the problem.

```
function sym(args) {
  //new array
  var newArray = [];

  //loops through however many arguments are inputted
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
    //loops through each argument array's items
    for(var j=0;j<arguments[i].length;j++) {
      //if the newArray array doesn't have the array item, it adds it to the new array, to avoid duplicates.
      if(newArray.indexOf(arguments[i][j]) === -1) {
        newArray = newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newArray.push` returns the *length* of the array that was pushed, not the array itself.

Remove the `newArray = newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);` and just make it `newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);` and your error should disappear.

Comment: Well, actually `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat :-)

Comment: That worked nicely thank you! It had me confused because I kept thinking it was a problem with the indexOf function itself.

Comment: @jeff64 console.log is your friend :-)

Answer (score 2):

Array.push() modifies the array and doesn't return it (but its new length), so instead of

```
newArray = newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);
```

simply use

```
newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);
```

Comment: `push` actually returns the (new) *length* of the array, not `null`.

Comment: push does **not** return null.

Comment: `Array.push() returns null` no, it returns the new length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

*Array.prototype.push* returns the new length property of the object upon which the method was called. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

After first loop iteration, `newArray` is a number, not an array.

So, fix the code:

```
 newArray.push(arguments[i][j]);
```